# How to merge two dataframes with overlapping data and special requirements?

Tags: python, database, dataframe

I have two dataframes with various columns (sometimes the same, sometimes mostly the same--could have extra columns).  I know this can be done with SQL or something else but I want to try to do it with Python.  Also it isn't only one ID this is just an example of one of the IDs in the data.

Rules are:
we trust df1 over df2 but if df1 is missing for a run of 20 (420-440) then I want df2 to override the -99 (missing) in df1.  I don't want any override in df1 if its not 20 feet.  it has to be 20 ft like this though (400-405, 405-410, 410-415, 415-420) so if there is a way to state what "origin" it starts from on the From/To that would be helpful.

df1

| ID | From | To | Q | RM | RQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MRC-10 | 0 | 5 | 0.005 | 15.0 | 10 |
| MRC-10 | 5 | 10 | 0.5 | 1.8 | 10 |
| MRC-10 | 10 | 15 | 0.21 | 10.7 | 20 |
| MRC-10 | 15 | 20 | 0.20 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 400 | 405 | 0.01 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 405 | 410 | 0.15 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 410 | 415 | 0.21 | 0.8 | 20 |
| MRC-17 | 415 | 420 | 0.20 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 420 | 425 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 425 | 430 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 430 | 435 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 435 | 440 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 26.67 |
| MRC-17 | 440 | 445 | 0.14 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 445 | 450 | -99.0 | 0.04 | 48.57 |
| MRC-15 | 100 | 105 | 10.1 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 105 | 110 | 1.5 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 110 | 115 | 8.8 | 0.8 | 20 |
| MRC-15 | 115 | 120 | 7.3 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 120 | 125 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 125 | 130 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 130 | 135 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 135 | 140 | -99.0 | -99.0 | 26.67 |
| MRC-15 | 140 | 145 | 15.4 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 145 | 150 | -99.0 | 0.04 | 48.57 |

df2

| ID | From | To | Q | RM | RQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MRC-22 | 0 | 150 | 0.12 | 0.75 | 10 |
| MRC-22 | 150 | 180 | 0.07 | 0.15 | 18 |
| MRC-23 | 0 | 55 | 0.04 | 0.16 | 20 |
| MRC-17 | 400 | 420 | 0.15 | 0.01 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 420 | 440 | 0.33 | 0.8 | -99.0 |
| MRC-17 | 440 | 460 | 0.21 | 0.8 | 20 |
| MRC-15 | 100 | 120 | 0.52 | 0.7 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 120 | 140 | 0.64 | 0.15 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 140 | 160 | 0.88 | 0.82 | 20 |

Resulting in Final (-99 means missing for numeric, X for char):

| ID | From | To | Q | RM | RQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MRC-10 | 0 | 5 | 0.005 | 15.0 | 10 |
| MRC-10 | 5 | 10 | 0.5 | 1.8 | 10 |
| MRC-10 | 10 | 15 | 0.21 | 10.7 | 20 |
| MRC-10 | 15 | 20 | 0.20 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 100 | 105 | 10.1 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 105 | 110 | 1.5 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 110 | 115 | 8.8 | 0.8 | 20 |
| MRC-15 | 115 | 120 | 7.3 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 120 | 125 | 0.64 | 0.15 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 125 | 130 | 0.64 | 0.15 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 130 | 135 | 0.64 | 0.15 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 135 | 140 | 0.64 | 0.15 | 26.67 |
| MRC-15 | 140 | 145 | 15.4 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-15 | 145 | 150 | -99.0 | 0.04 | 48.57 |
| MRC-17 | 400 | 405 | 0.01 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 405 | 410 | 0.15 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 410 | 415 | 0.21 | 0.8 | 20 |
| MRC-17 | 415 | 420 | 0.20 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 420 | 440 | 0.33 | 0.8 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 425 | 430 | 0.33 | 0.8 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 430 | 435 | 0.33 | 0.8 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 435 | 440 | 0.33 | 0.8 | 26.67 |
| MRC-17 | 440 | 445 | 0.14 | -99.0 | 10 |
| MRC-17 | 445 | 450 | -99.0 | 0.04 | 48.57 |
| MRC-22 | 0 | 150 | 0.12 | 0.75 | 10 |
| MRC-22 | 150 | 180 | 0.07 | 0.15 | 18 |
| MRC-23 | 0 | 55 | 0.04 | 0.16 | 20 |

All I have is the below so far that I want to share, the rest I've tried isn't great and didn't work (got blank for the result).  I think maybe I have to use mask since I used that before in something else (with the help of someone on here) but I'm unsure how to make this work.

```
# Load libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't understand your question. not very clear. can u give a pseudo code what u want or kind of sql or something like that.

Comment: I want a counter loop that goes through df1 and says ok check for a value in variable Q.  if there isn't a value for a run of 20 (0-5 5-10, 10-15, 15-20), I want it to check df2 and see if there is a value from 0-20 that can replace the missing.  In the above example, the 2nd set of 20 (From = 420, To = 440) is where we have 4 missing values or 20 feet of missing.  Then if you glance at the same interval on same ID in df2, you see 420-440 (To-From) has a Q value of 0.33.  Since it checks that box, I want it to replace the missing (-99.0) values sitting in df1. The result shows the answer.

Comment: Why does `Q` get `-99` in the last line? from what I understand, if the `From-To` of `df` is in the range of `From-To` of `df2` we change the `Q` value of `df1` to the `Q` value of `df2` that corresponds to that line, And 445-450 is in the range of 440-460

Comment: @no_hex I don't want to replace if its just one 5 foot interval (445-450)...only if its a repeated missing of 5,5,5,5 or 20 feet so 440-460 or 460-480, etc.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly straightforward method that does a group and merge per column of interest:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s1 = StringIO('''ID     From    To  Q   RM  RQ
MRC-17  400     405     0.01    -99.0   10
MRC-17  405     410     0.15    -99.0   10
MRC-17  410     415     0.21    0.8     20
MRC-17  415     420     0.20    -99.0   10
MRC-17  420     425     -99.0   -99.0   10
MRC-17  425     430     -99.0   -99.0   10
MRC-17  430     435     -99.0   -99.0   10
MRC-17  435     440     -99.0   -99.0   26.67
MRC-17  440     445     0.14    -99.0   10
MRC-17  445     450     -99.0   0.04    48.57
''')
s2 = StringIO('''ID     From    To  Q   RM  RQ
MRC-17  400     420     0.15    0.01    10
MRC-17  420     440     0.33    0.8     -99.0
MRC-17  440     460     0.21    0.8     20
''')

df1 = pd.read_csv(s1, delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv(s2, delim_whitespace=True)

'''
we trust df1 over df2 
if df1 is missing for a run of 20 (e.g. 420-440) then df2 overrides the -99 (missing) in df1
'''

for df in (df1, df2):
    df.replace(-99, np.nan, inplace=True)

df1['From20'] = (df1.From // 20) * 20
grouped = df1.groupby('From20')
for col in ('Q', 'RM'):
    needs_filling = ~grouped[col].any()
    idx = pd.Series(needs_filling.index[needs_filling], name='From')
    right = pd.merge(
        left=idx,       right=df2[['From', col]],
        left_on='From', right_on='From',
    )
    merged = pd.merge(
        how='left',
        left=df1.From20,  right=right,
        left_on='From20', right_on='From',
    )
    df1[col].fillna(merged[col], inplace=True)

print(df1)
```

```
       ID  From   To     Q    RM     RQ  From20
0  MRC-17   400  405  0.01   NaN  10.00     400
1  MRC-17   405  410  0.15   NaN  10.00     400
2  MRC-17   410  415  0.21  0.80  20.00     400
3  MRC-17   415  420  0.20   NaN  10.00     400
4  MRC-17   420  425  0.33  0.80  10.00     420
5  MRC-17   425  430  0.33  0.80  10.00     420
6  MRC-17   430  435  0.33  0.80  10.00     420
7  MRC-17   435  440  0.33  0.80  26.67     420
8  MRC-17   440  445  0.14   NaN  10.00     440
9  MRC-17   445  450   NaN  0.04  48.57     440
```

Comment: this definitely gets me started....do I need to sort first by ID first?

Comment: Probably, though I don't know for certain - you only showed one ID in your question

Comment: ok I updated it now with more IDs/data.  I tried the code you suggested and it only worked sometimes but not on all. I tried sorting first and that didn't do it either.  Still trying to work it out, thanks for all the help!

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: I want it to have all combinations of the files but if there are IDs that match with intervals do what you did above with preferring df1 or df2.  I tried it on the extended data and it leaves off MRC-22, MRC-23.

Comment: df2[~df2.ID.isin(df1.ID)].dropna() helps get the list not in df1

Comment: test = pd.concat([df1,df2nonmatch])   and then this seems to put the pieces together.  Maybe not the most efficient way but seems to work!

Comment: what if instead of 20 (maybe its not always 20 feet on the 2nd file df2) is there a way to write it where it compares the length (From minus To for df2) then uses that to fill in df1?

Comment: There is a way, but I suggest that that's outside of the scope of the current question - if you believe this current answer to adequately meet the needs of your current question as it stood originally, then the best course of action is to accept it, and file a new question with a specific minimum viable reproducible example for your "length" scenario